# Lua как подставить значение переменной в скрипт

Tags: lua

Как в items[" "] подставить значение из переменной current ?

Заранее спасибо.

```
os.setlocale("");
local items = { ["d20l"]=true, ["d20r"]=true, ["g16tl"]=false, ["g16tr"]=false }
local current = "d20l"
if items["d20l"] then
    print('Yes')
else
    print('No')
end
```

Comment: `items[" "] = current`

Comment: BTW, you can use empty string `items[""]` - empty string in Lua not equals to `nil`

Comment: Так просто же `items[current]`, не?

Comment: Работает! Спасибо. @Alexander Petrov